# How to make conditional overflow style in _document.js (Next.js)

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, next.js

How can I change the html and body overflow style based on the page.

For example on the about page html overflow is hidden, but body isn't, and then for the contact page body overflow is hidden and html is not

This issue was caused since I switched from vanilla css to the  Next UI library mid-way through the project. I'm looking for the quickest solution even if it is a little hacky.

Here is some pseudocode I have attempted:

```
<Html lang="en" if aboutpage style={{ overflow: "hidden" } else: style={{ overflow: "scroll" }}>
  <Head>{CssBaseline.flush()}</Head>
```

```js
import React from 'react';
import Document, { Html, Head, Main, NextScript } from 'next/document';
import { CssBaseline } from '@nextui-org/react';
import { useRouter } from "next/router";


class MyDocument extends Document {
  static async getInitialProps(ctx) {
    const initialProps = await Document.getInitialProps(ctx);
    return {
      ...initialProps,
      styles: React.Children.toArray([initialProps.styles])
    };
  }


  // const router = useRouter();   //causing an error?
  // console.log(router.pathname);
  render() {
    return (
      <Html lang="en" style={{ overflow: 'scroll' }}>
        <Head>{CssBaseline.flush()}</Head>
        <body  style={{ overflow: 'hidden' }}>
          <Main />
          <NextScript />
        </body>
      </Html>
    );
  }
}

export default MyDocument;
```

Thanks!

I tried to write some psudeocode. I'm not sure how to put a conditional statement code to change the Html tag and Body style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to update html and body overflow properties simply via `useEffect()` hook on any of the pages you want. For example in your about page, you could run this:

```
// On your about page for example
useEffect(() => {
    document.documentElement.style.overflow = "hidden";
    document.body.style.overflow = "scroll";
}, []);
```

After the page first gets rendered, you can edit style of the `documentElement` which is html tag and `body` as custom as you want.